# Duplicate row N times while incrementing integer field

Tags: amazon-redshift

#### Objective

I have a dataset which has a year in which an object was acquired and the lifespan of the object. I would like to create copies of each row, so that there is a row for each year of the object's lifespan. I would also like to increment the year column by one for each duplicate row.

#### Example

Here is a simple example of the data.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE "data"("year" int, lifespan int);
INSERT INTO "data"("year", lifespan) VALUES (2000,3), (2012,2), (2021,1);
SELECT * FROM "data";
```

which results in:

```
year   | lifespan
-------+----------
 2000  |        3
 2012  |        2
 2021  |        1
```

I was able to accomplish the duplication in PostgreSQL by using the `generate_series()` function, but it seems the function in Redshift accomplishes a quite different goal. Here is how I would accomplish this is PostgreSQL:

```
select *, generate_series(1, (lifespan)::integer) i from "data"
```

I could then use `row_number()`, `over`, and `partition` to increment the year field.

#### Desired Output

I would like to have data that looks like:

```
year   | lifespan
-------+----------
 2000  |        3
 2001  |        3
 2002  |        3
 2012  |        2
 2013  |        2
 2021  |        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive query for this (I used postgresql on db-fiddle but I tried it out on an actual redshift database):

**Schema (PostgreSQL v15)**

```
CREATE TABLE "data"("year" int, lifespan int);
INSERT INTO "data"("year", lifespan) VALUES (2000,3), (2012,2), (2021,1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH RECURSIVE rec(year, lifespan, remaining) AS (
    SELECT year, lifespan, lifespan
    FROM data

    UNION ALL

    SELECT year + 1, lifespan, remaining - 1
    FROM rec
    WHERE remaining > 1
)
SELECT year, lifespan
FROM rec
ORDER BY year;
```

| year | lifespan |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 3 |
| 2001 | 3 |
| 2002 | 3 |
| 2012 | 2 |
| 2013 | 2 |
| 2021 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n6grk7k6opj3GuiwnXMB73/0)